# Beef fat for frying

Tags: frying, beef, fat

Where do I purchase beef fat for frying fish? I have been using a solid fat of half vegetable and half beef fat, but have not been able to find beef fat only.

Answer (score 3):

beef fat or tallow can be found on amazon or gourmet cooking stores.

Other then that; local butcher.

If all else fails; you can render your own; the best cut is “leaf fat”; from around the kidneys on the cow.  Then you just render down; similar to clarifying butter.

Really depends on how much you need.

note:  Do not buy the hydrogenated junk at chain grocery stores